Implicit differentiation of $x^y = y^x$
I want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ where $x^y=y^x$.
This is what I have tried:

Some preparations.
$$x^y=e^{\ln(x^y)}=e^{y\ln(x)}$$
$$y^x=e^{\ln(y^x)}=e^{x\ln(y)}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}y\ln(x)=\frac{y}{x}+\frac{dy}{dx}\ln(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}x\ln(y)=\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}+\ln(y)$$

My actual "calculations".
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^y=y^x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{y\ln(x)}=e^{x\ln(y)})$$
$$\left(\frac{y}{x}+\frac{dy}{dx}\ln(x)\right )e^{y\ln(x)}=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{x}{y}+\ln(y)\right)e^{x\ln(y)}$$
$$\frac{y}{x}e^{y\ln(x)}+\frac{dy}{dx}\ln(x)\cdot e^{y\ln(x)}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{x}{y}e^{x\ln(y)}+\ln(y)\cdot e^{x\ln(y)}$$
$$\left(\ln(x)\cdot e^{y\ln(x)}-\frac{x}{y}e^{x\ln(y)}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=\ln(y)\cdot e^{x\ln(y)}-\frac{y}{x}e^{y\ln(x)}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\ln(y)\cdot y^x-\frac{y}{x}\cdot x^y}{\ln(x)\cdot x^y-\frac{x}{y}\cdot y^x}=\frac{\ln(y)\cdot y^x-yx^{y-1}}{\ln(x)\cdot x^y-xy^{x-1}}$$

My question is:
$$\frac{\ln(y)\cdot y^x-yx^{y-1}}{\ln(x)\cdot x^y-xy^{x-1}}\stackrel{?}{\equiv}\frac{xy\ln(y)-y^2}{xy\ln(x)-x^2}\stackrel{?}{\equiv}\frac{\ln(y)-\frac{y}{x}}{\ln(x)-\frac{x}{y}}$$
I want to make sure my process for finding the differentiation is correct.

Here's a direct demonstration: starting with the left hand side (and using the fact that $x^y = y^x$),
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(y)\cdot y^x-yx^{y-1}}{\ln(x)\cdot x^y-xy^{x-1}} &= 
\frac{\ln(y)\cdot y^x - \frac{y x^{y}}{x}}
{\ln(x)\cdot x^y - \frac{x y^{x}}{y}}
\\ & = 
\frac{\ln(y)\cdot x^y - \frac{y x^{y}}{x}}
{\ln(x)\cdot x^y - \frac{x x^y}{y}} 
\\ & = 
\frac{\ln(y)\cdot x^y - \frac{y x^{y}}{x}}
{\ln(x)\cdot x^y - \frac{x x^y}{y}} \cdot \frac{1/x^y}{1/x^y}
\\ & = 
\frac{\ln(y) - \frac{y}{x}}
{\ln(x) - \frac{x}{y}} \qquad [\text{RIGHT HAND SIDE}]
\\ & = 
\frac{\ln(y) - \frac{y}{x}}
{\ln(x) - \frac{x}{y}} \cdot \frac{xy}{xy}
\\ & = 
\frac{xy\ln(y) - y^2}
{xy\ln(x) - x^2}. \qquad [\text{MIDDLE}]
\end{align}

Incidentally, these derivatives are an interesting usage case for the multivariate chain rule. For instance, we could set up the differentiation of the right hand side of the original equation as follows.
$$
f(x) := y^x = u^v, \quad u(x) = y(x), \quad v(x) = x
$$
From there,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(y^x) = 
\frac{d f}{dx} = 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}
\\ = vu^{v-1} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} + \ln(u)u^v \cdot 1
\\ = xy^{x-1} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} + \ln(y)y^x
\\ = \left(\frac xy \frac{dy}{dx} + \ln(y) \right)y^x.
$$

Try this method once :
$$x^{y}=y^{x}$$
$$\implies y\ln(x)=x\ln(y)$$
$$\implies \frac{\ln(x)}{x}=\frac{\ln(y)}{y}$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\right)= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\ln(y)}{y}\right)$$
Now apply the quotient rule of differentiation.
Which implies that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=\frac{g(x)f'(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^{2}}$$
$$\implies \frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^{2}}=\left(\frac{1-\ln(y)}{y^{2}}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^{2}(1-\ln(x))}{x^{2}(1-\ln(y))}$$

It looks fine to me; the only subtle bit is in the first equality, where you have to subsititute $y^x$ for $x^y$ and vice-versa. But because you're computing this on the curve defined by that equality, it looks valid to me.
You're also dividing by $xy$, which means that you're implicitly assuming that neither of them is zero... you should confirm that this is valid and doesn't lose any solutions.
Finally, all this implicit differentiation stuff has some hypotheses -- namely the invertibility of a Jacobian -- that you'll want to check before you go applying implicit differentiation willy-nilly.

"you're losing the solutions (0,1) and (1,0); that might be a concern for you." So $0^1(=0)=1^0(=1)$? I never knew!

Thanks, Oscar. Brain fart. I'll edit.

This is all good, but let me suggest an easier way.  There is a "generalized power rule" that can be used, and you can separate out differentiation (without respect to a variable) and derivatives (with respect to a variable) and it becomes much more straightforward (at least I think so).
The generalized power rule is a linear combination of the power rule and the exponentiation rule:
$$d(q^r) = rq^{r - 1}\,dq + \ln(q)\, q^r\,dr$$
Therefore, you can differentiate as follows:
$$
x^y = y^x \\
d(x^y) = d(y^x) \\
yx^{y-1}dx + \ln(x)\, x^y dy = xy^{x-1}dy + \ln(y)\, y^x dx
$$
From here you can solve for the derivative algebraically:
$$
 \ln(x)\, x^y dy - xy^{x-1}dy = \ln(y)\, y^x dx - yx^{y-1}dx \\
 (\ln(x)\, x^y - xy^{x-1})\, dy = (\ln(y)\, y^x - yx^{y-1})\, dx \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\ln(y)\, y^x - yx^{y-1}}{\ln(x)\, x^y - xy^{x-1}}
$$
Personally I think that is a much more straightforward operation.

Do you mean this?
$$d(q^r)=rq^{r-1}dq+\ln(q)q^rdr\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\ln(y)\cdot y^x-yx^{y-1}}{\ln(x)\cdot x^y-xy^{x-1}}$$

@simulation_and_equations - yes - fixed, and thank you!
